# How to represent a system of quadratic equations in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matlab, quadratics

Suppose I have two quadratic equation like the following:

1. $2x^2 - 3x + 2$
2. $x^2 + 5x + 6$

I want to find the minimum values of these equation with the constraint that:

$-3 \lt x \lt 5$

How represent these situations in a matrix format? Actually I am trying to use matlab cvx, where I assume these are needed.

Thanks.

Comment: CVX seems to be for convex optimization. Why cannot you use those functions?

Comment: While not using CVX, [fminbnd](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) is a builtin function that finds the minimum of a single variable function.